# Java - make constructor without parameters mandatory

Tags: java, constructor

Is there a way for making constructor without parameters mandatory?

I thought that this example will work. You have classes A and B:

```
public class A {
    public A() {
        //do something
    }
}

public class B extends A {
    public B(int number) {
        //do something with number
    }
}
```

But you can not call `B b = new B();`, because class B does not have constructor without parameters. It has only constructor with number.

I was just playing with reflection in java and wanted to instantiate object from class (`class.newInstance()`). But to instantiate like this, you need constructor without parameters.

I am not asking now about reflection. I just want to know if there is a way to make no arg constructor mandatory or to be sure that class has mentioned constructor.

Comment: No, there isn't such a way.

Comment: You could add a test which goes through all your classes reflectively and fails when it finds a class which doesn't have a 0 arg constructor

Comment: Well just add the constructor... it's not really clear what you're asking. If you were going to modify the class to say "There should be a parameterless constructor" you could modify it to provide that instead...

Comment: This is horrible: Insist the class extends an abstract base class that throws an exception in the no arg constructor.  This way the only way to implement the class is to provide a no arg constructor that does not call the super class's constructor.  There are probably many ways in which this will fail badly in unexpected places.

Comment: @JonSkeet: I'm asking, if there is a way to be sure, that class that I'm going to instantiate has constructor without args.

Comment: @Pyro Yes, compile it.  If there isn't one, Java will provide one.  Viola, you're guaranteed that one exists.  The question you should probably be asking is: "Is there a way to guarantee the no arg constructor is accessible?"

Comment: Exactly. If you're using reflection, you'd have to check with reflection - but that would be the case anyway. Basically, consider what such a feature would look like... it would mean putting something in the class. That feature already exists, and the "something" you put in the class is a parameterless constructor...

Comment: @Tibrogargan Yes, but if you define other than default constructor, then default one will not be present anymore. So if you take example I provided in question, compiler (or IDE) will complain that there is no default constructor in class B.
And I know that this is horrible. I'm just curious :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly you want to make it mandatory for all classes to have a zero arg/default constructor. You could add a test which fails should you have any classes without such a constructor using the [Reflections library](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.reflections/reflections/0.9.10)

```
@Test
public void ensureAllClassesInPackageTempHaveAZeroArgConstructor() throws Exception {
    List<ClassLoader> classLoadersList = new LinkedList<>();
    classLoadersList.add(ClasspathHelper.contextClassLoader());
    classLoadersList.add(ClasspathHelper.staticClassLoader());

    Reflections reflections = new Reflections(new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .setScanners(new SubTypesScanner(false), new ResourcesScanner())
            .setUrls(ClasspathHelper.forClassLoader(classLoadersList.toArray(new ClassLoader[0])))
            .filterInputsBy(new FilterBuilder().include(FilterBuilder.prefix("temp"))));

    for (Class<?> clazz : reflections.getSubTypesOf(Object.class)) {
        boolean hasZeroArgConstructor = Arrays.asList(clazz.getConstructors()).stream().anyMatch(c -> c.getParameterCount() == 0);
        if (! hasZeroArgConstructor) {
            Assert.fail(String.format("%s doesn't have a zero arg constructor", clazz.getCanonicalName()));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The *only* way this could be done is if you provided a no-arg constructor in `B` which set `number` to some reasonable default (or let Java set it to 0).

```
public class B extends A {
    public B(int number) {
        //do something with number
    }

    public B() {
        // set number to a sane default
    }
}
```

Outside of that, there's no other way to accomplish what you're asking.  If you write any form of constructor, even one with no arguments, Java's implicit no-arg constructor is no longer considered.

Answer (score 0):

i think you can use constructor overloading in this situation:

```
public class A {
    public A() {
        //do something
    }
}

public class B extends A {
    public B(int number) {
        //do something with number
    }

    public B() {
        //do something with number
    }
}
```

Comment: I know that I can overload constructor, but I don't have to. I wanted to do something, so that I will need to define constructor without args in class or that it will be present from inherited class.